# Loading website within website in runtime

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web-component

Whats the best approach to load in runtime website within website? 
I want to have a website in which using a button you can load external html, js, css files most likely via http call add show that files in form of embedded website.
These external files could be whatever js app you can imagine react, angular etc.
Is this even possible?

Comment: Use an iframe??

Comment: are there any restrictions of using iframe? will it work with complex app with routing etc?

Comment: @UnderNotic https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: @UnderNotic It should work without any problem. However, an app (well, any page) can prevent itself from being loaded in an iframe (some frameworks do that by default, which is generally a good idea, mainly to prevent clickjacking) – https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: How about web components? Can this be done with import? Can whole website with routing react etc. can be wrapped into web component?